# Have anyone gone thru the example given in https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am facing some problems after using this example. In fact this is a very good source code to create action bar.

I used this in my application. But when I run my application, myapplication installed on the emulator but my application icon doesn't show on the emulator home screen.

I think i have missed something in my AndroidManifest File. Below is the code of my AndroidManifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.keepintouch.android.widget.actionbar"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="14"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <!-- 
        <activity android:name="com.keepintouch.android.KeepintouchActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         -->
    </application>

</manifest>
```

In my app i want to create an activity class but i cannot judge that In which package should I create my all activity file ? I think you can tell me that where have i created mistakes? Please tell me also that how should i create an activity file with action bar functionality ?

Comment: I have done this and also tested in in android 10 level successfully. Now I start to make my project by adding actionbar project as a library project and copy all files from actionbarexample directory to my project. I found no error when i use actionbar class in my project("KeepInTouch"). But when i start to run it on android 4.0.3 emulator i found an error in console.       Could not find KeepInTouch.apk!                                         I have also clean and rebuild my project but my problem remain same. Do you know why i am getting this error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

keep your package as

```
package="com.keepintouch.android"
```

and register your activity as

```
<activity android:name=".KeepintouchActivity"
```

need to add in your layout as

```
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.markupartist.android.yourActivty"
```

Comment: When i downloaded the zip file from https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar, It has two directory actionbar and actionbarexample. Should i use actionbar project as a library project and actionbarexample as my application?

Comment: ya you need to do like that. Or you can copy all the file and use in your project.

Comment: Can list the steps to make the action bar using android-actionbar?

Comment: Finally I have done it ? Can you please tell me that if i install this application apk file in my phone which has andoid 2.3 platform, will it work?

Comment: @NaveenChauhan ya it will work for >8 api version.